# Consultas entre varias tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla **`actividad`** que posee dos atributos: `creadoID` y `modificadoID` en relación con la tabla **`usuario`**.

He intentado realizar una consulta de actividades, donde por cada registro tome los datos del usuario de quien la creó y la modificó.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM actividad 
INNER JOIN usuario ON actividad.creadoID = usuario.id 
OR actividad.modificadoID = usuario.id
```

Comment: Y... ¿cuál es el problema? ¿Quieres las actividades `creadas Y modificadas por el mismo usuario` (**`AND`**)   o quieres las actividades `creadas O modificadas por el mismo usuario` (**`OR`**)?

Comment: Quiero saber cual es el usuario que la ha creado, y el otro que la ha modificado por registro de cada actividad. Con la sentencia que tengo, solo me trae un usuario.

Comment: De haber puesto tu comentario en la pregunta habría quedado bastante claro lo que querías, como la tienes planteada ahora mismo esa parte **esencial** de tu pregunta no se entendía. La solución de @sstan es el camino correcto para lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que yo entiendo es que quieres consultar los registros en la tabla `actividad`. Y para cada registro, quieres ver los detalles del que lo creó y modificó, detalles que están guaradados en la tabla `usuario`.

La solución es de hacerle join a la tabla `usuario` 2 veces:

```
select a.*,
       c.name as nombre_creador,
       m.name as nombre_modificador
  from actividad a
  join usuario c on c.id = a.creadoID
  join usuario m on m.id = a.modificadoID
```

Por supuesto, `c.name` y `m.name` son solo ejemplos porque no conozco los nombres de las columnas en tu tabla `usuario`. Reemplaza mi ejemplo en el `SELECT` con las columnas que necesitas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.